# How to add multiple test reports to SonarQube

Tags: go, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarScanner to scan a Go project.
Adding a unit tests report generated with `go test -json ./... > artifacts/test/report.json` works as expected when using the configuration setting `sonar.go.tests.reportPaths=artifacts/test/report.json` works as expected.

However, I have a 2nd (security) test report (coming from `gosec -fmt=sonarqube -no-fail -out=artifacts/test/gosec-report.json ./...`) which I would like to add to the reports. Therefore, I used the following call of the sonar-scanner with: `sonar.go.tests.reportPaths=artifacts/test/*.json`

Sadly it neither picks up the unit test report `report.json` nor the security test report `gosec-report.json`.

**How can I add both reports to SonarQube?**

```
sonar-scanner \
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*_test.go \
-Dsonar.projectKey="my-project" \
-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
-Dsonar.sources=. \
-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go \
-Dsonar.tests=. \
-Dsonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=artifacts/test/coverage.out \
-Dsonar.go.tests.reportPaths=artifacts/test/*.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the `reportPaths` parameters take a comma-delimited list of paths.
Examples from the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/):

> sonar.go.tests.reportPaths - Comma-delimited list of paths to unit test report files. Paths may be absolute or relative to project root.
>
> sonar.go.coverage.reportPaths - Comma-delimited list of paths to coverage report files. Path wildcards are supported (see above) since SonarGo 1.1.

You have to use this:

```
sonar-scanner \
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*_test.go \
-Dsonar.projectKey="my-project" \
-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
-Dsonar.sources=. \
-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go \
-Dsonar.tests=. \
-Dsonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=artifacts/test/coverage.out \
-Dsonar.go.tests.reportPaths=artifacts/test/report.json,artifacts/test/gosec-report.json
```